# Good tool for creating demo animations for Web pages?

Tags: javascript, animation, web, demo

I'm not finding any recent similar questions answered.  I want to create simple animations like that found here: http://hull.io

Any suggestions for tools to create and then deploy these?  I'm guessing this is a Javascript library.

Answer (score 1):

That site specifically is using jQuery, but if you're looking for a more interactive and interesting javascript library which uses a lot of 3d drawing and such like that, try processingjs:
http://processingjs.org/

Answer (score 1):

You could try out Adobe's offerings - Edge Animate

http://html.adobe.com/edge/animate/

I believe you can use it for free if you sign up for the free version of Adobe creative cloud.

Answer (score 1):

If you use wordpress, the [Slider Revolution](http://www.themepunch.com/codecanyon/revolution_wp/) plugin is the very best for that.

Otherwise, there are quite a few desktop apps for html5/css3 animation authoring:

Adobe Edge http://html.adobe.com/edge/animate/

Sencha Animator http://www.sencha.com/products/animator

Motion Composer http://www.aquafadas.com/en/motioncomposer/

Hype (Mac only) http://tumult.com/hype/

Answer (score 1):

I did the animation on hull.io. I used jQuery Transit http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/

This is a fantastic jQuery plugin to create CSS transformations.

Comment: Interesting! Just FYI, the animation has issues in (soon to be Webkit/Blink) Opera.